# Check if a user has voted on a Post, in the template

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here's my `Post` model:

**models**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=76)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...


class PostScore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='score')
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And here's my template. I want to do something like this... if the user has upvoted or downvoted the Post, then hide the upvote/downvote buttons:

```
{% if request.user in Post.has_answered %}
{% else %}
    <img src="upvote.png" class="upvote" />
    <img src="downvote.png" class="downvote" />
{% endif %}
```

I planned to do this by adding a `ManyToManyField` called `has_answered` to my `Post` model, but i'm unable to do that as I get this error:

```
post.Post.has_answered: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Post.has_answered' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Post.user'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Post.has_answered' or 'Post.user'.

post.Post.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Post.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Post.has_answered'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Post.user' or 'Post.has_answered'.
```

Any idea how I can fix this? I'm not too sure about the error message as I don't think I can alter my current `user` field.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your models to like this. You might not need PostScore model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # Other Fields i.e title, content, author ...
    upvotes = models.ManyToMany(User)
    downvotes = models.ManyToMany(User)
```

You can get upvotes on a Post using this.

```
upvotes = post_object.upvotes.count()
downvotes = post_object.downvotes.count()
```

To see whether user has upvoted or not,

```
if request.user in post_object.upvotes.all():
    # This user has upvoted this post
```

Same for downvotes.

You can do similar thing in your template as well and hide/show buttons based on condition.

```
{% if request.user in post_object.upvotes.all %}
    <!-- show upvote button highlighted -->
{% elif request.user in post_object.downvotes.all %}
    <!-- show downvote button highlighted -->
{% else %}
    <!-- Show both buttons (not highlighted) -->
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its a correct solution indeed, but wouldn't this be a performance issue if say we have ≈1000 users and/or ≈1000 upvotes/downvotes?

Comment: I can't add another `User` field in my `Post` model otherwise I get the error shown in my original question  .I already have `user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)` which is the author of the `Post`, and I can't remove that.

Comment: @EzzatA Maybe using exists() can improve the performance. 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#exists

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried send the `flag` from your django views to template like :

````
def myView(request):

    parameters['is_user_voted'] = PostScore.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).exists()
    .....
    .....
    send ```parameters``` to your template using render()
````

And change you template as:

```
{% if is_user_voted == 'True' %}
{% else %}
    <img src="upvote.png" class="upvote" />
    <img src="downvote.png" class="downvote" />
{% endif %}
```